# Django values_list returns unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode

I have the following queryset in a view:

```
cities = Idea.published.values_list('city', flat=True).distinct()
```

And the following in my corresponding template:

```
{% for city in cities %}
    <li><a href="{% url ideas-by-city city %}">{{ city }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

The {{ city }} variable prints out as a string on the rendered page, but the city variable passed into the url tag get represented as unicode: i.e u('city'). How do I pass this variable properly into the url tag?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting u('city')? with the parenthesis? unicode should look like u'city'. Check your def __unicode__(self) method of your city model and see if it is not returning something funny.

Comment: Argh. This isn't a "unicode" representation. This is a representation of a **tuple**, whose contents (like all Django strings) is in unicode. There's probably something wrong with your urlconf. Please show the exact output you get.

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying. It is a tuple with a unicode representation within. If I print it in the template like this {{ city }}, it shows up as, for example "Philadelphia". But if I use it in a {% url %} tag like this {% url ideas-by-city city %}, I get this template error: Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'ideas-by-city' with arguments '(u'Philadelphia',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: also to clarify, 'city' is not a model. It is a field value within the 'Idea' model. Hence, the values_list query.

Comment: Having looked over this again, I think the problem is with my view and not with the url tag.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

> iriencode

as in `{{ value|iriencode }}`. See [the Django builtins docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/) for more information.

Comment: thanks, but that does not seem to do it. Still get this error: Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'ideas-by-city' with arguments '(u'Philadelphia',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.